# how to implement or after group in regex pattern

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I want to get the thread-id from my urls in one pattern. The pattern should hat just one group (on level 1). My test Strings are:

```
https://www.mypage.com/thread-3306-page-32.html
https://www.mypage.com/thread-3306.html
https://www.mypage.com/Thread-String-Thread-Id
```

So I want a Pattern, that gives me for line 1 and 2 the number 3306 and for the last line "String-Thread-Id"

My current state is `.*[t|T]hread-(.*)[\-page.*|.html]`. But it fails at the end after the id. How to do it well? I also solved it like `.*Thread-(.*)|.*thread-(\\w+).*`, but this is with two groups not applicable for my java code.

Comment: If you use `.*?` at the start, you make that match lazy, meaning that it will stop at the first possible position and not at the last one (which causes your problem).

Comment: And you don't want square brackets here because `[\-page.*|.html]` matches only a single character. Use parentheses instead.

Comment: ...and I just noticed another problem...this regex needs more work. How exactly do you know that the ID is finished? At the end of the string, unless that end is `.html` or contains `-page`, in which case match before that?

Comment: it ends if there is a -page.* or .html or end is reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing if this fits for all situations, but I would try this:

```
^.*?thread-((?:(?!-page|\.html).)*)
```

In Java, that could look something like

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^.*?thread-((?:(?!-page|\\.html).)*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                  # Match start of line
.*?                # Match any number of characters, as few as possible
thread-            # until "thread-" is matched.
(                  # Then start a capturing group (number 1) to match:
 (?:               # (start of non-capturing group)
  (?!-page|\.html) # assert that neither "page-" nor ".html" follow
 .                 # then match any character
 )*                # repeat as often as possible
)                  # end of capturingn group
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I edited it a little bit, but thats waht I was seaching for
https://www.debuggex.com/r/C0TNhypy7TdEE-IL